# Pythagorean numbers pairwise coprime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Consider the equation 
\begin{equation}
x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2,~~~~~~~~~~(*)
\end{equation}
where $x,y,z \text{ and } a $ are positive integers.  It is easy to prove that exist infinite triples $x,y,z$ with $GCD(x,y,z)=1$ that satisfy $(*)$. Are there triples $x,y,z$ **pairwise coprime** satisfying $(*)$?

Note: By pairwise coprime we mean $GCD(x,y)=GCD(x,z)=GCD(y,z)=1$.

Comment: Consider the remainders modulo $4$.

Comment: You might want to look at Euler Bricks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick

Comment: Thanks, one should indeed look at remainders modulo 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mod $4$ there are only two possibilities for the left side:

$1+1+1$ and $1+1+0$, neither are quadratic residues $\mod 4$.